# Why are my textblocks being inconsistently placed on my WPF Canvas?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a DataTable of points and I'm attempting to place two diagonal lines to display the point and then have the point's name as a textblock displayed beside it. The two lines place perfectly in the correct positions, whereas the text is not in the correct position, although I'm using the exact same coordinates.

Here's my code:

```
public void DrawPoints(List<double> extents, double canvasWidth, double canvasHeight)
{
        DataRow[] points = Globals.DT.Select();
        
        foreach (DataRow row in points)
        {
            string name = row["Name"].ToString();
            List<double> coords = new List<double> {(double)row["Easting"], (double)row["Northing"]};
            double elevation = (double)row["Elevation"];

            DXFToCanvas dxfToCanvas = new DXFToCanvas();
            List<double> canvasCoords = dxfToCanvas.DXFCoordToCanvas(coords, extents, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

            // Create two diagonal lines for point
            double sizeFactor = 2;

            Line line1 = new Line();
            line1.X1 = canvasCoords[0] - sizeFactor;
            line1.Y1 = canvasCoords[1] - sizeFactor;
            line1.X2 = canvasCoords[0] + sizeFactor;
            line1.Y2 = canvasCoords[1] + sizeFactor;

            Line line2 = new Line();
            line2.X1 = canvasCoords[0] - sizeFactor;
            line2.Y1 = canvasCoords[1] + sizeFactor;
            line2.X2 = canvasCoords[0] + sizeFactor;  
            line2.Y2 = canvasCoords[1] - sizeFactor;

            SolidColorBrush redBrush = new SolidColorBrush();
            redBrush.Color = Colors.Red;

            line1.StrokeThickness = 0.5;
            line1.Stroke = redBrush;
            line2.StrokeThickness = 0.5;
            line2.Stroke = redBrush;

            map_page_canvas.Children.Add(line1);
            map_page_canvas.Children.Add(line2);

            // Create point labels
            TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock();
            textBlock.Text = name;
            textBlock.FontSize = 4;
            textBlock.Foreground = redBrush;
            
            ScaleTransform scaleTransform = new ScaleTransform();
            scaleTransform.ScaleY = -1;
            textBlock.RenderTransform = scaleTransform;

            Canvas.SetLeft(textBlock, canvasCoords[0]);
            Canvas.SetBottom(textBlock, canvasCoords[1]);

            map_page_canvas.Children.Add(textBlock);
        }
}
```

How is it possible that using the exact same coordinates to set both the lines and the textblock can result in the textblock being at different positions than the lines? I'm using the scaletransform because my canvas needed to be on a y increasing upwards coordinate system.

Comment: What is "the correct position"? How exactly does the produced output deviate from what you expect? What exactly is your code supposed to do? Did you simply forget to set RenderTransformOrigin?

Comment: You are using `Canvas.SetBottom(textBlock, canvasCoords[1])` to position the textblock vertically. I think that should be `Canvas.SetTop(textBlock, canvasCoords[1])` in order to correspond to `line.Y1 = canvasCoords[1]`. Also, you don't actually use the same values. as for the line coords you add/subtract 'scalefactor' of value `2`, for the textblock you don't.

Comment: @lidqy, changing it to SetTop fixed it. I had a bit of a misunderstanding of how that actually works it seems. Thank you.

Comment: @Andy "*Canvas.SetBottom will set the bottom of your textblock*" ... to a distance measured from the bottom of the Canvas.

Comment: @clemens. Oh dear.  Should have clicked through and read that in the docs.